# bound on matrix inverse with different elements

Tags: matrices, inverse, error-propagation

I'm hoping that someone can point me to some literature on the following.

Is there a way to bound the inverse of a matrix if I change the value of 1 element in that matrix.  Let's say I have a matrix $A$ and its inverse $A^{-1}$.  If I replace element $A(1,1)$ with $A(1,1)+\delta$ (and assuming the inverse still exists), is there some way to relate the error in the inverse of my perturbed matrix to the true inverse?

thanks

Comment: See the comments to this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686687/sherman-morrison-formula-for-rank-1-update) for techniques for rank-1-updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace $A$ by $A+δ e_1e_1^T$, then by the formulas of Sherman, Woodbury and Morrison the determinant obeys $\det(I+uv^T)=1+v^Tu$, i.e.,

$$\det(A+δ e_1e_1^T)=\det(A)(1+δe_1^TA^{-1}e_1)$$

and the inverse follows from $(I+uv^T)(I+cuv^T)=I+(1+c+cv^Tu)uv^T$ for $c=-(1+v^Tu)^{-1}$, that is for the perturbed $A$

\begin{align}
(A+δ\, e_1e_1^T)^{-1}
&=A^{-1}(I-(1+δ\,e_1^TA^{-1}e_1)^{-1}\,δ\,e_1e_1^TA^{-1})\\
&=\frac{A^{-1}(1+δ\,e_1^TA^{-1}e_1)-δ\,A^{-1}e_1e_1^TA^{-1}}{1+δ\,e_1^TA^{-1}e_1}
\end{align}

So a very coarse   estimate is

$$\|(A+δ\, e_1e_1^T)^{-1}\|\le\frac{\|A^{-1}\|\,(1+2δ\|A^{-1}\|)}{1-δ\|A^{-1}\|}$$

---

Using the first form of the inverse, this can be improved to
\begin{align}
\|(A+δ\, e_1e_1^T)^{-1}\|
&\le\|A^{-1}\|\left(1+\frac{δ\|A^{-1}\|}{1-δ\|A^{-1}\|}\right)\\
&=\frac{\|A^{-1}\|}{1-δ\|A^{-1}\|}
\end{align}